# Scheduled functions to call every 2 minutes in PM2 but old execuetion is auto terminating

Tags: node.js, cron, web-hosting, pm2, amazon-linux

I have implemented a function in js file using **nodejs** application things are working fine but when I try to run every 2 minutes with the help of **pm2**
Every 2 mins my execution started auto but the issue is auto terminate old process.

```
 pm2 restart inbox.js --cron "*/2 * * * *"

 pm2 start inbox.js --cron "*/2 * * * *"
```

1st execution 12:00 AM

2nd execution 12:02 AM

3rd execution 12:04 AM

When start 2nd execution then 1st execution auto terminate
when start 3rd execution then 2nd execution auto terminate

I want to keep running all execution until all execution done

**App built** : nodejs and expressjs

**Os**: amazon-linux

Answer (score 0):

Replace `restart` with `start` and try again

Comment: thanks for suggestion. still no luck old process terminating while new process begins .